# Python library for editing XML preserving formatting and comments

Tags: python, xml, dom

I need to make a few changes to existing XML files, while preserving formatting and comments - everything except the minor changes I do should be untouched. I've tried xml.etree and lxml.etree with no success.

The XML is generated by my IDE, but its editor is lacking in functionality, so I have to make a few manual changes. I want to keep the formatting so the diffs are pretty and not polluting my history.

With the multitude of python XML libraries I thought I'd ask here if anyone has done something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Specifically, with its identity transform you can preserve XML as is and adjust or remove text nodes with minimal changes. Python's `lxml` can run XSLT or Python can call [external processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) such as Xalan and Saxon.

Below demonstrates how to update the text node of an existing node or remove node entirely by value.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
    
    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ADJUST NODE CONTENT -->
    <xsl:template match="key[text()='value']">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:text>new value</xsl:text>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- EMPTY TEMPLATE TO REMOVE NODE -->
    <xsl:template match="key[text()='value']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```py
import lxml.etree as lx

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc = lx.parse("input.xml")
style = lx.parse("style.xsl")

# CONFIGURE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
transformer = lx.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
result.write_output("output.xml")
```

Answer (score -2):

How many and what kind of changes do you need to make?  It sounds to me like you may be better served simply using a standalone XML editor (just Google for them, there are lots).  Frankly, I'm kind of surprised your IDE doesn't have adequate search-and-replace for your needs.  (Most of the ones I've seen even have regex facilities for this.)  If you really do need to write a program to make the XML changes, and you don't want to mess up the formatting and comments, your best bet may be to open the XML as a regular text file in Python, and use its regular expression library (`import re`) to do the search-and-replace.

Comment: It's a bunch of XML with localization, one file per language. Basically I want to be able to rename a key, and have it renamed in all the other languages. I also want to be able to delete keys that aren't present in the base translation.